# Office Open XML filename field

Tags: xslt, ms-word

I am using XSLT to transform a dynamically create a word document. According to the documentation [here](http://officeopenxml.com/WPfieldInstructions.php) I can use something like the following to get the current filename into my document:

```
                        <w:fldSimple w:instr="FILENAME">
                            <w:r>
                                <w:rPr>
                                    <w:noProof/>
                                </w:rPr>
                                <w:t>DEFAULT NAME</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:fldSimple>
```

The documentation seems to contradict itself [here](http://officeopenxml.com/WPfieldDefinitions.php) in the field definitions and `FILENAME` is not actually supported (it is not in the list and clearly doesn't work). When I use the same block of logic and `TIME` instead of `FILENAME`, the time field actively updates every time I open the document. Is there a different way to get the documents current file name?

[Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-filename-field-a2946f1b-d822-47dc-ba32-4482aece26bc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) looks like it should be supported as well.

Comment: Some (a very few) field types update automatically when a document is opened. Others require explicit update. There's a setting you can write into the Open XMLdocument that will trigger an update, but it will require the user to confirm a prompt (security consideration). I'm currently on a mobile device and can't give you the exact name of this setting...

Comment: > Is there a different way to get the documents current file name?


Not sure how 'different' you mean, but typing `?ActiveDocument.FullName` into the VBA immediate window will tell you the path and fileName, you can also use .Net, py,... instead of VBA

Comment: @CindyMeister, I will look into it thank you.

Comment: @SlowLearner, sorry I meant different as in using the same technology (I was hoping I am just missing something from documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cindy Meister, I found out my document was not updating on open but `FILENAME` is supported as expected. When I add

`w:dirty="true"` to my `fldSimple` I get a prompt on opening the word document (security protocol) and the `FILENAME` updates correctly.

Comment: Yep, that's it :-) The alternative is to use Word Automation Services (part of SharePoint) to open the document before passing it on to the user.